# ActionBar Title not show for specific fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I've 4 different fragments, however it doesn't show the title for any of the fragments. When i created the fragments, everything was working fine, however now no title shows up on the actionBar. I've done all the changes which i found on the stackoverflow, but non of them worked for me

the code for my main activity is :-

```
 private ActionBar toolbar;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = getSupportActionBar();
    toolbar.setTitle("Home");
    loadFragment(new home());

    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

}

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        Fragment fragment;
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()){

            case R.id.navigation_home:
                toolbar.setTitle("Home");
                fragment = new home();
                loadFragment(fragment);
                return true;

            case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                toolbar.setTitle("Dashboard");
                fragment = new Dashboard();
                loadFragment(fragment);
                return true;

            case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                toolbar.setTitle("Notifications");
                fragment = new Notification();
                loadFragment(fragment);
                return true;

            case R.id.navigation_profile:
                toolbar.setTitle("Profile");
                fragment = new Profile();
                loadFragment(fragment);
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
};

private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment){

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

the code for one of the fragments which contains widgets(Rest of them are yet empty) is below :-

```
private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

Button AskForHelp, Drafts, LogOut, Settings;

View view;

public Dashboard() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public static Dashboard newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    Dashboard fragment = new Dashboard();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container,false);

    AskForHelp = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.askHelp);
    AskForHelp.setOnClickListener(this);

    Drafts = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.drafts);
    Drafts.setOnClickListener(this);

    LogOut = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.logOut);
    LogOut.setOnClickListener(this);

    Settings = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.settings);
    Settings.setOnClickListener(this);

    return view;

}

public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()){

        case R.id.askHelp:
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), Questions.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;

        case R.id.drafts:
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Function not enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        case R.id.logOut:
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Function not enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        case R.id.settings:
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Function not enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }

}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

I've tried almost everything mentioned below. But it's still the same

Comment: You might be clearing your activity toolbar title in some other fragment.

Comment: Have you checked out the theme, you know some themes have no action bar as their behaviour

Comment: All the other fragments are auto generated.....i haven't started coding them

Comment: The theme is Default AppTheme

Answer (score 0):

In fragment just put this line in `onCreatView` so it will set your fragment title each time when you load your fragment.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getActivity().setTitle("you title here");
...
}
```